# Keep getting an error message while creating a pivot table in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table

I am having difficulty in generating a pivot table from a data table in SQL as I keep getting the same error message and do not understand really why.

My initial table has the following shape (I'm just filtering the ones I will use):

```
== ID == | == Category == | == Description == | == ...
   ID1   |   Category_A   |   Description_1   |   ...
   ID2   |   Category_B   |   Description_2   |   ...
   ID3   |   Category_C   |   Description_3   |   ...
   ID3   |   Category_A   |   Description_4   |   ...
   ID1   |   Category_B   |   Description_2   |   ...
   ID4   |   Category_C   |   Description_3   |   ...
   ID5   |   Category_A   |   Description_1   |   ...
   ID2   |   Category_A   |   Description_1   |   ...
   ID2   |   Category_A   |   Description_4   |   ...
   ID5   |   Category_B   |   Description_2   |   ...
   ID4   |   Category_B   |   Description_6   |   ...
   ID4   |   Category_C   |   Description_7   |   ...
```

It is a table where each row represents an event description for a specific ID. There are many event description for a given ID, that's why an ID can appear on several row. The column Category is just the category of the event description.

From this table, my final goal is to obtain to something like this:

```
== ID == | == Description_1 == | == Description_2 == | == Description_3 == | = ...
   ID1   |         1           |          2          |         2
   ID2   |         0           |          1          |         1
   ID3   |         2           |          0          |         1
   ID4   |         0           |          1          |         2
   ID5   |         0           |          3          |         0
```

There are thousands of different IDs and hundreds of different descriptions.

Here is the code I tried:

```sql
WITH agg_table AS (
  SELECT ID, Description, COUNT(*) as description_count
  FROM original_table
  WHERE Category IN ('Category_A', 'Category_B', 'Category_D')
  GROUP BY ID, Description
  ORDER BY ID
)
SELECT *
FROM agg_table 
PIVOT (
      SUM(description_count) 
      FOR Description IN (SELECT DISTINCT Description
                          FROM original_table
                          WHERE Category IN ('Category_A', 'Category_B', 'Category_D'))
) AS pivot_table
```

From the original table, I group by the ID and the description to get a 3 column table where each row gives the number of times a specific event description happens for a specific ID (I also filter to only get specific categories ..). Then I use the pivot function to pivot the table and get what I would like to obtain: a table where I have one row for each ID, and each column represents a description event with the value of the cell indicating how many times a description happens for a given ID.

The problem is I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: mismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 9)
```

I really do not know where is the issue in the code. I read somewhere that it may be cause by aliases, but even without writing aliases, I still have the problem.

I don't know this has an impact on my case, but I am using databricks with Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11

Thank you in advance for your time. And please let me know if something was not clear so I can bring more details.

Have a nice day!

Comment: In databases that support `PIVOT` (which is not standard functionality), the column list needs to consist of constants.  You seem to want a dynamic pivot, and that requires generating the code as a string, which in turn depends on the database you are using.